# Is there an inherently ambiguous language which can not be recognized by Deterministic LBA?

Tags: complexity-classes, fl.formal-languages, computability, automata-theory

Is there inherently ambiguous language which can not be recognized by Deterministic LBA?

For example, $L=\{wv: w,v=(x|y)^*, w=w^R,v=v^R\}$, is there any deterministc LBA that recognizes $L$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Every* context-free language, whether inherently ambiguous or not, is recognized by some deterministic LBA.  This is Exercise 9.8 (a) in Hopcroft and Ullman's *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation*.  Even more is true; see Exercise 9.8 (b).